# How to stop default azure functions logger from sending trace events but allow it to send other event types (Request, Dependency)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am facing an issue where I am getting duplicate trace logs that are being sent to application insights through my Azure FunctionApp. I have narrowed down the issue to be because I have multiple logging providers. These logging providers are Serilog and the "default application insights logger".

LoggingProviders in my service-collection:

1. Default application insights logging provider
   [image: Default logging provider image]
2. Serilog logging provider
   S[image: erilog logging provider image]

It is possible for me to remove the default logger from the ServiceCollection, but this prevents other telemetry events such as request, and dependency from going to application-insights. My serilog logger is unable to catch these.

Therefore I had a question. I want only serilog to send trace events. Is it possible to mute trace events from the default application insights logger and allow all other events to be logged? If not, is it possible to log request and dependency events from the Serilog logger itself? Thank you.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

As I mentioned above, I have tried to remove the default logger from the serivcecollection and it was able to stop the duplicate logs issue. However, it seems like Function Apps rely on this logger to send Request and Dependency Events which I need as well. After removing this logger I was not able to get these events.

I was also able to find a raised issue of this on github:

https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/157

In this issue "fariz-huseynov" raises the point that there are keys that when added to configs automatically enable the default logger. I have observed this also but it seems like only the default logger can send Request, Dependency event logs.

**HOW I AM REGISTERING SERILOG**

```
var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration
{
    ConnectionString =  appSettings.application_insights_connection_string
};

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, dispose: true));
```

**EXAMPLES**
[image: Duplicate Logs example]

Raw log data of first log:

```
{
    "name": "AppTraces",
    "time": "2023-10-17T00:37:50.5456099Z",
    "iKey": "25f0502c-1ad4-4f1d-bee2-f916bf75e51e",
    "tags": {
        "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "A0F00Z5Z220400C",
        "ai.location.ip": "0.0.0.0",
        "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "azurefunctionscoretools: 4.0.5413",
        "ai.internal.nodeName": "A0F00Z5Z220400C"
    },
    "data": {
        "baseType": "MessageData",
        "baseData": {
            "ver": 2,
            "message": "Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.",
            "severityLevel": "Information",
            "properties": {
                "HostInstanceId": "cc60e187-b5ae-4be8-a7b6-3bac2c17b77e",
                "Category": "Host.Triggers.DurableTask",
                "prop__{OriginalFormat}": "Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.",
                "ProcessId": "29300",
                "LogLevel": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Raw log data of second log:

```
{
    "name": "AppTraces",
    "time": "2023-10-17T00:37:50.5546176Z",
    "iKey": "25f0502c-1ad4-4f1d-bee2-f916bf75e51e",
    "tags": {
        "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "A0F00Z5Z220400C",
        "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "dotnetc:2.21.0-429"
    },
    "data": {
        "baseType": "MessageData",
        "baseData": {
            "ver": 2,
            "message": "Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.",
            "severityLevel": "Information",
            "properties": {
                "MessageTemplate": "Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.",
                "SourceContext": "Host.Triggers.DurableTask"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code which you have configured to send the traces and also share the screencap of the Traces.

Comment: What is the framework of your Function App?

Comment: Hello, I am using .NET6.0. Also, my AzureFunctionsVersion is v4. I have added my code for how I am adding serilog as well as an image and log data of the duplicate logs. Please view when you can.